# No Overload matches this call: Typescript error

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

im building a spotify clone with nextjs & typescript.

When user attempts to subscribe to the service, the redirect to spotify is succesfull and completes. On return however the user is not added as a subscriber and state does not change.

Below is the code for the create-checkout-component that handles the above. And also code for the helper that makes the API call:

```
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

import { stripe } from '@/libs/stripe';
import { getURL } from '@/libs/helpers';
import { createOrRetrieveCustomer } from '@/libs/supabaseAdmin';

export async function POST(
  request: Request
) {
  const { price, quantity = 1, metadata = {} } = await request.json();

  try {
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });      
      
    const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

    const customer = await createOrRetrieveCustomer({
      uuid: user?.id || '',
      email: user?.email || ''
    });

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      billing_address_collection: 'required',
      customer,
      line_items: [
        {
          price: price.id,
          quantity
        }
      ],
      mode: 'subscription',
      allow_promotion_codes: true,
      subscription_data: {
        trial_from_plan: true,
        metadata
      },
      success_url: `${getURL()}/account`,
      cancel_url: `${getURL()}/`
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ sessionId: session.id });
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err);
    return new NextResponse('Internal Error', { status: 500 });
  }
}

// Below is the helper that makes the API call:
```

I have tried changes to the code, and read the stripe docs but haven't been successful in resolving the issue.

Comment: Could you maybe share some of the code you wrote for the part that is intended to "add a user as a subscriber" and "change the state" and details of how/when that code would get called? The code presented doesn't do any of that, it just creates and redirects to a Stripe CheckoutSession. The things you're mentioning would usually take place in e.g. a webhook handler function.

Comment: I figured out a solution. The version of the  Stripe API i am using is not compartible with Typescript. i added a comment //@ts-ignore above the code and the error went away.